# Any way to prevent this brute force method from throwing StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, recursion, brute-force

```
// this is the recursive method used to crack the 3 digit password
// takes three integer arguments each representing the index of a letter in the above alphabet string
public static String brute(int a, int b, int c) {
    // boolean signifying whether or not the password was correct
    boolean isCorrect = false;

    // string variable representing the password as a concatenation of characters from the alphabet string
    String string = "" + alphabet.charAt(a) + alphabet.charAt(b) + alphabet.charAt(c);
    System.out.println(string);

    try {
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("protected3.zip");
        zip.setPassword(string);
        zip.extractAll("contents");
        System.out.println("Successfully cracked!");
        isCorrect = true;
    } catch (ZipException ze) {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    
    // base case
    if (isCorrect) {
        return string;
    }
    // recursive steps
    else {
        if (alphabet.length() - 1 <= c) {
            return brute(a, b + 1, 0);
        }
        else if (alphabet.length() - 1 <= b) {
            return brute(a + 1, 0, c);
        }
        else {
            return brute(a, b, c + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have a method that is meant to brute force a 3 digit lowercase password on a zip file recursively. It works correctly, but once the password attempts get to around "fff" the program throws a StackOverflowError. I know that intense recursion is taxing on the stack, but is there any way around this problem with recursion or will I have to re-implement this as a not-so elegant loop? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could always increase the size of the stack.

Comment: Can you, please, provide a link to the `ZipFile` API you are using? I don't see methods `setPassword (String)` and `extractAll (String)` in [Oracle's `ZipFile` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) .

Comment: Why do you open the Zip file at each recursive call? Why not open it once, and pass it as an argument? Or, have the file an instance variable, and open it in the constructor. (Note the 2nd option will require `brute` to be an instance method.)

Comment: The second comment in the example code references "the above alphabet string", but the referenced string is not present. The example code refers to the variable `alphabet` several times, but the example code includes neither a declaration nor initialization for that variable.

Comment: More importantly, why is this recursive? This is not a problem that needs recursion for its solution.

Comment: You are getting StackOverflow because in the average case you will consume `len(alphabet)^3/2` stack frames.  The recursive approach is a non-starter.

Comment: In the project outline there's a footnote that says "Note that trying to figure out all possible three character strings over an alphabet is a great place to use recursion!", which is why I took the recursive approach. Reading that again though, and along with your comments I see I may have misinterpreted this a bit. Thanks for the help!

Comment: All recursions can be replaced with a cycle.

Comment: @cyrus60 _"...is a great place to use recursion"_ - Whoever wrote that does not understand where recursion is useful.

Comment: If you know the password will always be 3 characters, you could simply have 3 nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is fine but your algorithm is broken. It needs a depth-first search, ie a level of recursion per letter, ie 3.

The problem is that all the logical branches in brute() besides when the unzip works, simply call brute().

You need to add a condition for the end of the alphabet to return without calling brute().